# Need only 1 run option in vscode Python

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

[image]

Need help with running code in vscode.

As you can see in the image, if I click on the run button, 2 options are coming.

I need to remove 1 option so that I can run code with a single click.

Note that I am using the code runner extension.

Comment: Check this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909100/coderunner-setup-in-vsc-for-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909100/coderunner-setup-in-vsc-for-python)