# CodeRunner Setup in VSC for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I've installed VSC and added to it the C/C++ and CodeRunner extensions, and it all worked perfectly. I've set CodeRunner to run in Terminal and I haven't done much else to the settings.

However, I installed the Python extension now, and the CodeRunner 'Run' button displays 2 options when I click it: Run Code and Run Python File in Terminal. When I was running a C program previously, one click on 'Run' would do it.

Is there any way to eliminate the extra options when running Python code? Essentially, I just want the program to execute with one click on 'Run'. Seems like the code executes regardless of the option I choose. (See the attached picture). Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reason:
   In VS Code, the green run button provided by the "Python" extension is to execute the command "`Run Python File in Terminal`". It only requires us to click once to run python files in the Terminal of VS Code:

   [image]

   When we also use the extension "Code Runner", the run button ("Run Code") provided by it defaults to output results in "OUTPUT". In the previous use, this button will cover the green button provided by the "python" extension, but now that they are integrated, we can choose the execution method.
2. For setting `"code-runner.runInTerminal": false,` it determines whether the "code runner" runs in the "Terminal", the commands they execute are different:

   "*Run Code*"：`python -u "/python_file.py"`

   "*Run Python File in Terminal*": `/python.exe /python_file.py`
3. Solution: You could use F5 to debug the code or try to close the "Code Runner" extension. (Click "`Enable`" to restore the use of the extension.)

Reference: [Run Python File in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_run-hello-world).